# Django test module ignores choice restrictions

Tags: django, testing, django-models

So I have a model that has restricted choices, 'Developer' and 'Charity'. If I change the radiobutton values on the actual form to something other than those, Django comes back with an error message as it should. But in testing it accepts any value it seems. So in short the test shouldn't fail but it does. Or the Django should raise an integrity error or something.

I actually have another problem testing for a foreign key field in the profile, but that's perhaps best saved for a different question.

Model code snippet:

```
# models.py
user_type       = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices={
                    ('Developer', 'Developer'),
                    ('Charity', 'Charity'),
                    }, blank=False, null=False)
```

However, when I do the following in testing, there's no error message:

```
 # tests.py
 def test_no_user_type(self):
        my_values = self.DEFAULT_VALUES
        my_values[self.USER_TYPE] = 'something'
            # this row creates and saves the user and the profile.
        user, profile   = self.save_user(my_values)
            # I thought this bit would be irrelevant at this point because 
            # there should be an error message 
        test_correct = (profile.user_type != 'something')
        self.assertEqual(test_correct, True)

def save_user(self, values):
    user = User.objects.create()
    user.username           = values[self.USERNAME]
    user.email              = values[self.EMAIL]
    user.set_password(values[self.PASSWORD])
    user.save()
    profile                 = user.get_profile()
            ...     
            profile.user_type       = values[self.USER_TYPE]
            ...

    profile.save()
    return user, profile



# constants from the top
PASSWORD        = 1
EMAIL           = 2
USER_TYPE       = 3
...
FIELD_LIST = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'user_type']
...
DEFAULT_VALUES = ['test_username', 'test_password', 'test_email@test.com', 'Developer']
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a model form (including the Django admin), Django will validate the model instance. In other cases, you must call the instance's [`full_clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method manually to validate it.

Comment: Thank you, it was as simple as that.